Cannot find module '../page/home/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
when i use vue3+ts ,my router are right,but it's tips that cannot find module '../page/home/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations always!
I was used hash modules,not history modules.
i hope that someone can help me to solve this problem.

Are you using Vetur the VScode extension?

！thanks！I find why have this fault。thank you

you are right！I just saw my code，I forgot used vetur extension ！ but I build  new one！
